# Downloading Ubuntu 15.04 on an Acer Chromebook C720 and Stuck at this screen

Tags: acer, chromebook

I have an Acer Chromebook C720. I was kinda fed up with the Chrome OS so I decided to try downloading a different OS, and my friends told me that Ubuntu could be easily installed. I searched up the instructions, had no problem following them until after I finished the installation process, had it all installed, it opened a loading screen, and popped me to the Ubuntu 15.04 chrubuntu tty1 startup page. There I tried to login. The set of instructions I used told me to use user as my username as well as my password. As soon as I did that, I got a long block of text, but I haven't figured how to actually boot up the operating system and use my computer. It's giving me an option to type in a command, but even after searching the web, I haven't found anything that I can do. I still have the option to go back to the Chrome OS but I'd rather not. Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It's a little unclear what you are describing here.  It sounds like you've installed ubuntu to the internal ssd , but you said chrubuntu.  Could you at least provide us with a screenshot ? You could post it to imgur, because you're reputation 1 user and cannot post images yet. In my experience,when I installed Ubuntu to the internal ssd, all I had to do is boot the machine, press a shortcut ( I think it was Ctrl + D  ) on the OS verification screen, and then it just boots to ubuntu. Does this sound any close ?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this same issue as well. One of my colleagues noted that some of the text said there was a read only file that could not be written to, and also said that it might be that whatever user was not allowed to write to the Chrubuntu partition. Did you also happen to get strange questions in the installation process on driver packages that seemed to have been recently patched, or something along those lines? I don't quite remember what it said but I know the default answer was no.